# Вычислить s = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + ... + x^2n (|x| < 1). Вычисления прекратить, когда очередной член суммы будет меньше ε = 0,0001. VBA

Tags: циклы, vba

нужна помощь с задачей. Не понимаю, почему результат выводит неверный. Условия в задании, нужно использовать циклы.

```vbs
Sub n4()
    Dim s As Double, x As Double, e As Double, n As Double
    e = 0.0001
    x = InputBox("Введите x меньше единицы:")
    n = 0
    s = 0
    Do Until x > e
        s = x ^ (2 * n) + s
        n = n + 1
        If x < e Then Exit Do
    Loop
    MsgBox (s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Какие данные задаете, какой результат получается, какой результат должен быть?

Comment: Вообще, по условию цикл должен прекращаться когда член суммы (т.е. x^ (2*n)) меньше эпсилон, а вы x проверяете на это условие.

Comment: *s = 1+(числа_в _четной_степени >0)* - меньше единицы ну никак не получится. Что-то с условиями напутано или должно быть *е>1*

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub n4()
    Dim s As Double, x As Double, n As Long
    Const e As Double = 1.221
    
    x = InputBox("Введите x меньше единицы:")
    If x >= 1 Then MsgBox ("Ошибка"): Exit Sub
    
    Do
        s = x ^ (2 * n) + s
        n = n + 1
    Loop Until s > e
    
    MsgBox s, 64, "РЕЗУЛЬТАТ"
End Sub
```

Comment: А почему у вас Loop Until s > e, если по условию вычисления должны прекратиться если очередной x ^ (2n) будет меньше эпсилона. И ещё почему e = 1.221?

Comment: Это для примера, т.к. ну, никак не может быть `s<1`. e - опять же, "от фонаря". Или задавать х>1 и х>е, или что-то eще менять в условиях. Или я не понял задачу :)